# How to make MacBook Air touchpad usable?

Tags: xorg, mouse, touchpad, macbook

I'm trying to setup Ubuntu so that my touchpad on MacBook Air works.

I've successfully installed and am using mtrack, but it still doesn't work. Acceleration is horrible, and the cursor jumps around apparently randomly.

I've edited my xorg.conf file according to tutorials I could find.

I'd like to fix acceleration, and possibly right-clicking by clicking on the bottom-right corner.

Any help appreciated, here's my xorg.conf:

```
Section "InputClass"
MatchIsTouchpad "on"
Identifier      "Touchpads"
Driver          "mtrack"
Option          "Sensitivity" "0.55"
Option      "FingerHigh" "12"
Option      "FingerLow" "1"
Option          "IgnoreThumb" "true"
Option          "IgnorePalm" "true"
Option          "TapButton1" "0"
Option          "TapButton2" "0"
Option          "TapButton3" "0"
Option          "TapButton4" "0"
Option          "ClickFinger1" "1"
Option          "ClickFinger2" "3"
Option          "ClickFinger3" "3"
Option          "ButtonMoveEmulate" "false"
Option      "ButtonIntegrated" "true"
Option          "ClickTime" "25"
Option          "BottomEdge" "25"
Option      "SwipeLeftButton" "8"
Option      "SwipeRightButton" "9"
Option      "SwipeUpButton" "0"
Option      "SwipeDownButton" "0"
Option      "ScrollDistance" "75"
EndSection
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest maybe looking at `mtrack`

I notice you have it configured, but a good idea to check :)

You can get it installed and configured like this:

- `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-mtrack`
- `sudo nano /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf`

Change the input section to be something similar to this:

```
Section "InputClass"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        Identifier      "Touchpads"
        Driver          "mtrack"
        Option          "Sensitivity" "0.95"
        Option          "FingerHigh" "12"
        Option          "FingerLow" "1"
        Option          "IgnoreThumb" "true"
        Option          "IgnorePalm" "true"
        Option          "TapButton1" "0"
        Option          "TapButton2" "0"
        Option          "TapButton3" "0"
        Option          "TapButton4" "0"
        Option          "ClickFinger1" "1"
        Option          "ClickFinger2" "3"
        Option          "ClickFinger3" "3"
        Option          "ButtonMoveEmulate" "false"
        Option          "ButtonIntegrated" "true"
        Option          "ClickTime" "25"
        Option          "BottomEdge" "25"
        Option          "SwipeLeftButton" "8"
        Option          "SwipeRightButton" "9"
        Option          "SwipeUpButton" "0"
        Option          "SwipeDownButton" "0"
        Option          "ScrollDistance" "75"
        Option          "ScrollUpButton" "5"
        Option          "ScrollDownButton" "4"
EndSection
```

- Save your config with `ctrl+x` and `y` to save and quit nano
- Reboot

I hope that helps!

Good luck :)

Comment: Yup, I already have it like I was saying, and x.org logs show that it's loading mtrack.

Comment: Hmmm, I wonder.  Have you tried adding `SUSPEND_MODULES="bcm5974"` to your `/usr/lib/pm-utils/defaults`?

Comment: I didn't! What does it do?

Comment: Hopefully, it should trigger a restart of the bcm module when it realizes it's not in suspend mode.

Comment: Woops!  I just found a bug report.  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1586552

Comment: Apparently it's been fixed in the mainline, but has yet to be rolled out.  Here's the mainline build: http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.4.24/ you can install the mainline kernel using the details from here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds